# Django: Filter ListView on Groups / Iterate queryset over list

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, usergroups

Given a User can belong to more than one Group, I would like to ask how to filter on Groups in the below scenario.

In Django I have a ListView showing a **product list**.

- I have two groups: Company_1, Company_2.
- I have 5 users: Worker_1, Worker_2, Worker_3, Worker_4, Inspector
- Worker_1, Worker_2, belongs to "Company_1"
- Worker_3, Worker_4, belongs to "Company_2"
- "Inspector" can inspect all Products from both Companies

Inspector has no superuser status or staff status, It should be seen as a normal user that belongs to two groups ['Company_1', 'Company_2']

**Desired functionality:**

Worker_1 register their own manufactured products in the application and can see a list of all products manufactured by Company_1.

Inspector can see all products, from Company_1 and Company_2

In the below code attempts, however, Inspector cannot see any products.

As Inspector belongs to ['Company_1', 'Company_2'] I need a way to check each Group membership in the list against the Group registered for a product.
Please note that below are simplified into two groups but in reality x number of groups and users.

**in models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Product(models.Model):
    worker = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.company = list(self.worker.groups.all().values_list('name', flat=True))
        super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**within views.py**

```
class ProductListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'product_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(ProductListView, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(company__contains=list(self.request.user.groups.all().values_list('name', flat=True)))
```

Comment: What does `"Admin" belongs to both groups.` mean? Is Admin a superuser or a staff or a normal user that in both groups? If your definition of Admin is clear, then you could simply add a condition in your get_queryset to return different query sets for normal user and Admin user.

Comment: Hi Jun, I have clarified above, and re-named Admin to Inspector. See it as a user that belongs to two groups and therefore have access to see all products from both groups. Please show in code if you see an easy solution here, and I will award your help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a really ugly solution, but have to work for now. Ideally, I need to figure out a dynamic way to express this. The real problem was to dynamically construct filters and combine those, especially with the manual construct of " | ". There might exist a better solution, but for now I couldn't find it, or figure it out.

```
class ProductListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'product_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(ProductListView, self).get_queryset()

        f = []
        for g in self.request.user.groups.all():
            f.append(f'{g}')

        d = len(f)

        if d == 0:
            g = queryset.filter(company__contains=f"")
        elif d == 1:
            g = queryset.filter(company__contains=f[0])
        elif d == 2:
            g = queryset.filter(company__contains=f[0]) | queryset.filter(company__contains=f[1])
        elif d == 3:
            g = queryset.filter(company__contains=f[0]) | queryset.filter(company__contains=f[1]) \
                | queryset.filter(company__contains=f[2])
        elif d == 4:
            g = queryset.filter(company__contains=f[0]) | queryset.filter(company__contains=f[1]) \
                | queryset.filter(company__contains=f[2]) | queryset.filter(company__contains=f[3])
        elif d == 5:
            g = queryset.filter(company__contains=f[0]) | queryset.filter(company__contains=f[1]) \
                | queryset.filter(company__contains=f[2]) | queryset.filter(company__contains=f[3]) \
                | queryset.filter(company__contains=f[4])
        elif d == 6:
            g = queryset.filter(company__contains=f[0]) | queryset.filter(company__contains=f[1]) \
                | queryset.filter(company__contains=f[2]) | queryset.filter(company__contains=f[3]) \
                | queryset.filter(company__contains=f[4]) | queryset.filter(company__contains=f[5])
        else:
            g = queryset

        return g
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your definition of the inspector is clear, we can then add some conditions in the get_queryset function. Here is a pseudo-code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group

class ProductListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'product_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        Company1 = Group.objects.get(name='Company1')
        Company2 = Group.objects.get(name='Company2')
        inspectors = User.objects.filter(groups=Company1 and groups=Company2).distinct() 
        if self.request.user in inspectors:
            return queryset.filter(company=Company1 or company=Company2).distinct().values_list('name', flat=True)))
        return queryset.filter(company__contains=list(self.request.user.groups.all().values_list('name', flat=True)))
```

I hope this helps, let me know if it's not working :)

Comment: Thanks Jun, I will look at it, but I am ideally looking for an ability to generalising the code so I can add Company3, ... Company20 without the need to re-write the view. My usage of 'company__contains=' was an attempt to achieve this. as company field under model Product can contain a list ['Company1', Company2'... 'CompanyN']

Comment: The requirement you mentioned here is different from the question mentioned in your main question as you are saying the inspector user should be in all groups rather than Company1 and Company2. I would suggest the inspector can be classified as a separate group called `InspectorGroup` as there must be other groups which are quite different from the use of inspector group. Then it will simplify the check statement and the rest of other designs.